# How to update changes to Azure app service after it's deployed from CLI

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

IDE used is VSCode.

Deployment is done using CLI

The command I am using doesn't update it as I have checked the code files using ssh under development tools in azure portal

`az webapp update  --name <name> --resource-group <resource group name>`

Comment: What do you want to update in Azure WebApp ?

Comment: Do you want to push the changes made to code in deployed Azure WebApp ?

Comment: @Harshitha Yes, push the changes with CLI

Comment: With `az webapp update .. ` command we can set the parameters, you cannot push changes with this.

Comment: @Harshitha Oh, so I have to redeploy each time? No other way?

Comment: As you have mentioned , your code files are under SSH,you might have deployed under Azure Linux App Service Plan. You can go with FTP.

Answer (score 3):

- I have created Azure Linux Web App with the command which you have provided in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73802807/azure-ftps-how-to-find-the-deployed-project-files).

```cs
 az webapp up --resource-group YourRGName --location westus  --os-type Linux --runtime "PYTHON:3.9" --sku B1
```

[image]

- We can check the deployed files/folders from Azure Portal => `Development Tools` => `Advanced Tools` => `Go` => `SSH`
  **OR**
  `Development Tools` => `Advanced Tools` => `SSH`

[image]

- As we have deployed Sample WebApp from CLI, we can only see the `hostingstart.html`.
- If you want to add/update any files, you can connect to FTP and push the changes.
- We can find the FTP credentials in Portal
  `Deployment` => `Deployment Center`     => `FTPS Credentials`
  These credentials can be used for both `FTP/WINSCP`.

[image]

- All the files have to be under `wwwroot` folder.

> az webapp update --name  --resource-group

The above command is used to update and manage the deployed webapp Configurations.

Comment: I see `hostingstart.html` aswell, but I have a lot of files that I see under `tmp` folder, where I also run migrations. So if I can't find my files, how am I supposed to update it?

Comment: You can push the new file..

Comment: I don't think that's gonna work, without any of the files being there, how it is going to work if I change one of 100 files and upload that one file. The file system works differently. Do you know how the file system works? But where are the deployed files in the first place?

Comment: Please share the Image of your folder structure, and the file which you want to update.

Comment: Okay, `But where are the deployed files now ?`

Comment: Check even the `site` - `home/site` folder as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the deployment source in deployment center-> settings:

[image: details]

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the quickstart guide, you can deploy code updates like this:

```
az webapp up --name xxx --resource-group yyy
```

i.e., using your original `az webapp up` command with all the optional flags, and additionally adding the `--name` and `--resource-group` that you'll find the Azure dashboard.