# Azure FTPS How to find the deployed project files

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure FTP to update the project files after they are deployed via CLI

I get to `/site/wwwroot`

I see a tar file, where do I find all the project files.

Requirement is to update single file each time to test it.

CMD used

`az webapp up --resource-group <resourcegroupname> --location <location> --plan <plan_name> --os-type Linux --runtime "python|3.9" --sku B1`

Comment: Could you please share the project folder structure ? `they are deployed via CLI` , please share the command which you have used to deploy.

Comment: If the app is deployed correctly, all the files will be under `wwwroot` directory.

Comment: @Harshitha cmd is updated, app is deployed correctly as it is working for me, only issue is the updates. Under `wwwroot` all i see is tar file with a few other files

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update files in an App Service via Azure CLI
[image]
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=cli

Please, follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=cli)

Comment: My app is up and running, it's just a REST API, to get and store in mysql database. When I connect with FTP, I see nothing under `wwwroot`

Comment: Is the App Service have this setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT? Is it true or false?